# How do I duplicate a particle system and keep its settings separate from the original?

Tags: particles

When I select "Duplicate particle systems" a copy of the first particle system is created. This copy can be edited in Particle edit and I can even add new particles there. But if I change any settings (for example, change Children, Root, Material & etc.), then these settings also change in first particle system. How can I duplicate a particle system so that I can edit the copy, but that this doesn't affect the first particle system?

[image]

[image]

Comment: In question at this link, particles was not required to be changed in Edit mode. Therefore, this is not what I need. I need to be able to change settings after particles have been changed with brushes (Comb, Smooth, Add, Length, Puff, Cut, Weight) in Edit mode.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure not being able edit the particles is related to duplicating the particle system? I think the question could do with being edited to be a bit clearer because looking at the answer below and its comments there is obviously some confusion about what you are asking.

Comment: I already don't know how to say it right. I just want to know how I can change settings of duplicate copy, but so that settings of original don't change. After editing in Particle edit, settings where I can unlink copy from original become inaccessible & accordingly, any changes in copy are also duplicated in original.

Answer (score 1):

Do exactly what Sanbaldo said, BUT using <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> when duplicating the object instead of <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. Then those steps will work!
Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

you have to play with system block and data block so you don't have the same particle system applied twice. Probably you'll need to click on that "files" icon [image] (that let you duplicate the particle system, starting from a cloned version of the original one)

This is correct:

[image]

check how to work with different emitter settings:

[image]

this is wrong (see the number 2 that means that the particle system is used twice)

[image]

Comment: This only works when particles have not been modified in Particle edit. Once hair has been changed in Particle edit, these settings become unavailable.

Comment: This comment is not clear to me. Can you explain better the problem you have?

Comment: OK I'll try. Suppose I want to make 2 frames. I made hairstyle. Then I want to duplicate ready hairstyle & slightly change settings for second frame. I need hairstyle to remain the same but I want to make it more shaggy. I.e. I want to change settings in Children for example. But Blender doesn't allow changing settings only in duplicated version.

Comment: Again I don't fully understand, cause It's possible to do what you are asking for. Check again my screenshots and see that you need to have 2 particle system index and 2 particle settings (that need to be different, so no "2" number that means that you are using it twice)

Comment: check the video in my answer

Comment: Here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8msP.gif

Answer (score 0):

Have the same problem - the controls become inactive once I edit the hair via particles edit mode (i.e. comb, grow etc). It seems to be impossible to detach the duplicated hair system without losing hair comb data. Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I get what they are asking cause I have the same issue. I have a animal head that I groomed. The first groom is to determine flow and is done with the first particle system. I want to add some more randomness to the hair, but keep all the groom settings I just made in the particle editor. So when I duplicate the particle system, I need to be able to duplicate the particle settings, but be able to change the child settings without changing my first particle setting. Thus, I need a duplicate of the original settings. Currently it links the original settings only.

Thankfully, someone made an addon for this that works with Blender 2.93 beta
https://blenderartists.org/t/duplicate-edited-hair-particles/1247900